# Increment value of array of objects redux

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I need to increment quantity of item in cart if item already exists in the state array. In the reducer I got it to work but it needs to be immutable. Because of this, my component doesnt update properly.

This is the code for my reducer:

```
import { ADD_TO_CART, REMOVE_FROM_CART } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = [];

//Cannot mutate array in reducer 

export default function(state = initialState, action){
    const { type, payload } = action;

    switch(type){
        case ADD_TO_CART:
            const newState = [...state]
            for(var i = 0; i < newState.length; i++){
                if(newState[i].item.uid === payload.item.uid){
                    newState[i].item.qty ++;
                    return [...newState];
                }
            }
            return [...state, payload];
        case REMOVE_FROM_CART:
            for(var j = 0; j < state.length; j++){
                    if(state[j].item.uid === payload.uid){
                        state[j].item.qty = 1;
                    }
            }
            return state.filter(cartItem => cartItem.item.uid !== payload.uid);

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

I need to increment qty if item is already in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I see is with `newState[i].item.qty++;`, that although you shallowly copied the array, the elements in the array still represent those of the previous state, so post incrementing it mutates the object.

To resolve this issue you should also copy each item into a new object, *then* update the *new* object reference.

The following also include a minor optimization to iterate the data once versus twice, by checking for the matching item ID *as* it copying the state into a new array.

```
let itemExists = false;
const newState = state.map(item => {
  const newItem = { ...item };
  if (newItem.item.uid === payload.item.uid) {
    itemExists = true;
    newItem.item.qty = item.qty + 1;
  }
  return newItem;
});

if (!itemExists) newState.push(payload);

return newState;
```

**EDIT:** Alternative method

```
const itemIndex = state.findIndex(item => item.item.id === payload.item.id);
if (itemIndex !== -1) {
  return state.map((item, i) => ({
    ...item,
    item: {
      ...item.item,
      qty: item.item.qty + (itemIndex === i ? 1 : 0),
    }
  }));
} else {
  return [...state, payload];
}
```

Comment: Almost got it but unfortunately i ran redux immutable state invariant and it gave an error: A state mutation was detected inside a dispatch, in the path: `cart.0.item.qty`. Take a look at the reducer(s) handling the action {"type":"ADD_TO_CART","payload":{"item":{"name":"hamburger","price":12,"category":"dinner","qty":2,"uid":"d23ff8-4056-38b6-7e3-41ec8e01871"}}}.

Comment: @chrus54321 Updated answer, try `newItem.qty = item.qty + 1;` it's a more common pattern anyway and *shouldn't* mutate any old references. If that doesn't work then I have another idea.

Comment: @chrus54321 Ok, one thing I just noticed is your state array elements use a nested `item` key, so my first answer may have missed this and maybe that is the mutation your testing picked up on. I've updated it and added the alternative method I was thinking of.